# Concatenation of Strings in Prolog

Tags: string, prolog, concatenation, string-concatenation

I am trying to concatenate 4 strings in Prolog. I am able to concatenate 2 and 3 strings but I can't get it to work with 4. This is what I have so far:

```
join2(String1,String2,Newstring) :-
   name(String1,L1), name(String2,L2),
   append(L1,L2,Newlist),
   name(Newstring,Newlist).

join3(String1,String2,String3,Newstring) :-
   join2(String1,String2,S),
   join2(S,String3,Newstring).

join4(String1,String2,String3,String4,Newstring) :-
   join3(String1,String2,String3,Newstring),
     join2(String1,String2,S),
     join2(S,String3,Newstring).
   join3(Newstring,String4,Newstring).
```

Comment: `join4(String1,String2,String3,String4,Newstring) :- atomic_list_concat([String1,String2,String3,String4],Newstring).`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your constraints are, but you can also use SWI's `append/2` and `maplist/3`:

```
concatenate(StringList, StringResult) :-
    maplist(atom_chars, StringList, Lists),
    append(Lists, List),
    atom_chars(StringResult, List).
```

Then you can concatenate as many as you like:

```
?- concatenate(["hello", ", ", "world"], String).
String = 'hello, world'.

?- concatenate(["hey, ", "you ", "don't ", "say!"], String).
String = 'hey, you don\'t say!'.

?-
```

Note that the above assumes you are using the *default* setting in SWI Prolog:

```
:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes,atom).
```

where `"abc"` represents a Prolog atom and is equivalent to `'abc'`.

Comment: @false indeed, that's correct. I was rolling with what the OP understood and used in their original question.

Comment: `:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes,chars).`

Answer (score 1):

You'll need at least 2 intermediate *NewString*s in order to join 4 strings, but your proposed solution only uses 1 (`S`), although it tries to use `NewString` as both an intermediate and the final result.

Take what you did for `join3` a step further:

```
join4(S1,S2,S3,S4,NS) :-
    join2(S1,S2,NS12),
    join2(S3,S4,NS34),
    join2(NS12,NS34,NS).
```